# Clarification regarding 'Boyle's Temperature' definition

Tags: pressure, kinetic-theory, gas

In the Boyles law def- "The temperature at which a real gas obeys ideal gas law over an appreciable range of pressure is called Boyle temperature."
Why "over an appreciable range of pressure" is necessary.

Because the way i see it is this-[image]
after the critical point we see the isotherms are still not hyperbolas i.e the gas is still behaving like real gas. I think if we continue to increase temp we'll attain boyles temp and isotherms will become perfect hyperbolas. That's it. I do not see any need of "range" here.

Comment: image source- https://www.collegesidekick.com/study-guides/physics/13-5-phase-changes

Comment: One will certainly not get "perfect hyperbolas". Depending on the gas there will be a limited range of temperatures well above what the diagram shows and well below the next phase transition region (before molecular dissociation, ionization etc.) in which the gas will behave close to ideal. That temperature range is not as large as one might think. For water vapor it's probably "only" somewhere between 1000K and 2000K, so maybe it's not even a 3:1 or even 2:1 temperature range. Nitrogen might do a bit better and the noble gases are probably better still, but "ideal gas regions" are limited.